# How can I make notifications larger, so less text is cropped?

Tags: high-sierra, notifications

I am using Monotony to see news headlines as notifications. I have set it to "Alert style" so they are slightly larger and stay there until I click them. However I would like the notifications to be a bit larger so that less text is cropped. Right now too much is cropped to even read a headline.

Is this possible, either through the default notification system or by installing some other notification system?

Following screenshot shows that a typical headline and article summary are not readable:

[image]